# ExpressJs in undifine value get (to show [object])

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I learn **expressjs**, in which I pass the value, but do not come into the output.I have **created** a new `Routes file` and want to be a **function** with `Route methods`, so this is **done**. But then if I set **Route paths** in it, I don't get its value in the output. This `route path` will **match**, but value not get.. So help me and Solve.

This is my **Routes file**(`user.js`)

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()


app.get('/user/pq*xd', function(req, res) {
    res.send("User Data accessed: "+req.params)
});


module.exports = app
```

**URL** :- `http://localhost:3000/user/pq15A5yxd`

---

This case output is :- `User Data accessed:`

not display url value. How to Solve it.

Comment: Try converting the object to a string: `res.send("User Data accessed: "+JSON.stringify(req.params))
`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`req.params` This value to return Object So try `req.params[0]` to get URL value..

/Yout code is...

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()


app.get('/user/pq*xd', function(req, res) {
    res.send("User Data accessed: "+req.params[0])
});


module.exports = app
```

**Browser URL**:- http://localhost:3000/user/pq15A5yxd

**The output is**:- User Data accessed: **15A5y**

---

Routing refers to how an application’s endpoints (URIs) respond to client requests. For an introduction to routing, see [Basic routing](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/basic-routing.html).

**Route methods**

A route method is derived from one of the HTTP methods, and is attached to an instance of the express class.
The following code is an example of routes that are defined for the GET and the POST methods to the root of the app.

```
// GET method route
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('GET request to the homepage')
})

// POST method route
app.post('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('POST request to the homepage')
})
```

**Route paths**

Route paths, in combination with a request method, define the endpoints at which requests can be made. Route paths can be strings, string patterns, or regular expressions.
The characters ?, +, *, and () are subsets of their regular expression counterparts. The hyphen (-) and the dot (.) are interpreted literally by string-based paths.

Here are some examples of route paths based on string patterns.

This route path will match acd and abcd.

```
app.get('/ab?cd', function (req, res) {
  res.send('ab?cd')
})
```

---

For more information [click here.](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html)

Answer (score 1):

This is not how you define params for a route. If you want to define params for a route, you need to use this symbol `:`. Also, as someone already said in a comment, better stringify that object so you can actually read its contents.

An example could be

```js
app.get('/user/:param', function(req, res) {
    res.send("User Data accessed: "+JSON.stringify(req.params))
});
```

Now the result of the get `http://localhost:3000/user/pq15A5yxd` will be:
`User Data accessed: {"param": "pq15A5yxd"}`
This because by using `:param` you have defined a parameter named "param" on your route

Comment: you are very welcome. Thought this could help as you said you are on the process of learning express!